# Google Script API routexl error 409

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm trying to make a script which works out the fastest route to pass multiple locations, with the help of the routexl API.  However, everything I try seems to come up with an error 409 Truncated server response.  My code is as follows.

```
 function myFunctionpost() {
      var url = "https://api.routexl.nl/distances";
      var places = [{"address":"1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"}];
      var locations = JSON.stringify(places);
      var headers = { 
          "Authorization":"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("Username:password"),
          "Content-Type":"application/json"
      };
      var options = { 
          'method' : 'post',
          'headers' : headers,
          'contentType': 'application/json',
          'payload' : locations,
          'muteHttpExceptions' : true
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      //var json = response.getContentText();
      //var data = JSON.parse(json);
      Logger.log(response);
  }
```

Comment: Add `muteHttpExceptions:true` to your options. A 409 could mean the service doesn't like your payload. With muteHttpExceptions on there may be more data in the response.

Comment: Thanks @SpencerEaston I added this as you suggest, which gave me another issue of 'Syntax Error, Unexpected token: N' on the line 'var data = JSON.parse(json);', so i just commented this out for now to log the response.  The new information this has given us in the logs is 'No input found'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 409 error indicates there is [no input](https://www.routexl.nl/blog/api/?lang=en#response) found. I am no Google Apps expert, but the RouteXL API expects "locations" as input parameter. In your example the locations JSON is posted without the locations key.

Update: after some testing on Google Apps Script, I also found the ContentType needs to be adjusted.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
function myFunctionpost() {
      var url = "https://api.routexl.nl/distances";
      var places = [{"address":"1","lat":"52.05429","lng":"4.248618"},{"address":"2","lat":"52.076892","lng":"4.26975"},{"address":"3","lat":"51.669946","lng":"5.61852"}];
      var locations = JSON.stringify(places);
      var headers = { 
          "Authorization":"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("username:password")
      };
      var options = { 
          'method' : 'post',
          'headers' : headers,
          'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'payload' : {'locations': locations},
          'muteHttpExceptions' : true
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      //var json = response.getContentText();
      //var data = JSON.parse(json);
      Logger.log(response);
  }
```

Comment: Just need to JSON.stringify the payload value and that should do it.

Comment: @SpencerEaston Wasn't it already? var locations = JSON.stringify(places);

Comment: I signed up to test this. I've tried every combination of posting the data and I can not make it work. I'm even using the example data from the API docs...I can hit the status page just the distance endpoint will not accept the post data in any form.

Comment: @SpencerEaston Thank you for testing. As I went into Google Apps Script and found the problem in the ContentType, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. The API doc's should be updated to show that. They weren't specific but gave the impression to use JSON encoding

Comment: Thanks @SpencerEaston and RouteXL this has sorted my problem!

Comment: Great! Added some code based on this to [our examples](https://github.com/routexl/RouteXL-API-Connector)